# React-Native: How to dynamically set the height of the FlatList and make flatList fill screen?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm studying RN and has some problem in my project.
I hope do like this [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHIcC.jpg) in my porject

This is my code:

```
<View style={{ height: Dimensions.get('window').height }}>
    <StatusBar translucent={true} backgroundColor='#00000000' />

    <View>
        ...... something here......
    </View>

    <View style={{ flex: 1}}>
          <FlatList
              data={jobList}
              onEndReached={jobListOnEndReached}
              onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
              renderItem={renderJobList}
              height={pxToDp(100)}
              onScrollBeginDrag={() => setScroll(true)}
          />
    </View>
</View?
```

and now it looks like  [`it`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cif7d.png).
I wish when I pull up the FlatList I can make the FlatList fill the screen like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwDtg.png).
I tried  to use the 'Animated' prop but I don't how to make it work.

Comment: Try adding `style={{ flex: 1 }}` to the `View` containing your `FlatList`

Comment: What goes in the first `View` ? You could also make it a fixed height

Comment: Sorry, I have already add ```style={{ flex: 1 }}```  to the ```View``` containing ```FlatList```. I want update the height of FlatList  when pull up the FlatList.

Answer (score 0):

You can add to your Flatlist style `height` and `width` and should do the job. Check out the demo snack: [@abranhe/stackoverflow-56739086](https://snack.expo.io/@abranhe/stackoverflow-56739086)

[image]

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, FlatList, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const data = [
  { number: 1 },
  { number: 2 },
  { number: 3 },
  { number: 4 },
  { number: 5 },
];

export default () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Something Here</Text>
      <View style={styles.content}>
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Text style={styles.item}>item{item.number}</Text>
          )}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  content: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '80%',
  },
  item: {
    margin: 10,
  },
});
```

**Update**

Update because of the question's author comment! If you want to view more items and be able to scroll just add more items to the data.

[image]

Comment: Thank you but it's not my purpose. I have uploaded one gif picture (https://imgur.com/HpyE3Xu). That's what I want to do.

Comment: @neohuiji it's exactly the same thing, to be able to scroll just add more data and that's it! I already edited the answer for you!

Comment: Thank you for your response, but what I want is when I pull up the FlatList , ``` something here ``` will be removed out of screen by some way such as 'absolute position' or others . I guess I need to subtract the height I pull up every time when I pull up this page until the FlatList is on the top of page.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [parallax](https://github.com/i6mi6/react-native-parallax-scroll-view)?

Comment: @pianoman102 Sorry for the late reply, That's what I want and I have already solve my problem. Only need to use  ```ListHeaderComponent ``` , It will work.